# Load tif images in Vaadin

Tags: java, image, vaadin, frontend

I could not load a tif image with `Vaadin 7 rc1`

Here are the some of the alternatoves I have tried:

```
String basepath = VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
Image image = new Image("Image", new FileResource(new File(basePath + "myPath/image.tif")));

Embedded image = new Embedded("Image", new ThemeResource("/pathToResource/imgae.jtif"));
```

In both cases the image was where the path pointed. Moreover if I had a `jpg` or `png` image in the same directory it was shown without a problem.

Does Vaadin 7 rc1 not support `tif` images?

Comment: J2SE does not support TIF.  You need [tag:JAI] for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real question here is that if your browser supports TIFF images. Take a look at [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support).

For cross-browser compatibility, I suggest you to convert your images to **PNG** or **JPG**.